# Is there a way to convert certain values from an input and display others in a sequential order?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, I am trying to create a DNA to RNA sequence converter, but it isn't really displaying when I try to get the values and change them sequentially. I.E., when you type certain letters like ATG they will convert into UAC but in that specific order. Is there a way to? I've already tried an array but it isn't working.

JS:

```
   var dna = document.getElementById("input1").value;
         var rna = [];
        var aminoacid;


        function replace(){
        if (dna.indexOf('a') > -1)
        {
         rna.push("u");
        } else if(dna.indexOf('t') > -1){
            rna.push("a");

        } else if(dna.indexOf('c') > -1){
            rna.push("g");

        }
        else if(dna.indexOf('g') > -1){
            rna.push("c");

        }


        }

        document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = rna;
```

HTML:

```
  <input style="top: -350px;" placeholder="Type DNA's value..." onclick="onClick();" id="input1">

  <button type="button" onclick="getInputValue();" id = "button1" style = "position: relative; z-index: 100; top: -300px; left: -200px;">Get RNA</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be what you are looking for:

```js
const input = document.querySelector('#input1').value,
      total = document.querySelector('#total');

let rna = input.replaceAll(/[atcg]/g, e =>
  e == 'a' ? 'u' :
  e == 't' ? 'a' :
  e == 'c' ? 'g' :
  e == 'g' ? 'c' :
  ' '
);

total.textContent = rna;
```

Comment: It is saying that the declaration or statement is undeclared

Comment: Never mind, I think it is fine.

Comment: is there a way to apply many characters at once instead of just 1? Like is in a string instead of a single character?

Comment: I will gladly accept your answer after! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can use `String.prototype.replace()` for this.

[Replace docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

For example:

```
let DNA = 'ATG'
DNA = DNA.replace('A', 'U');
DNA = DNA.replace('T', 'A');
DNA = DNA.replace('G', 'C');
console.log(DNA);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have several problems:

- You are getting the value of the input immediately (before anyone has
  had a chance to enter anything.
- You are attempting to produce the output immediately (your code that
  shows the result is outside of the function).
- You are trying to directly show an array, rather than the contents of
  the array.
- Because you are using `else if`, your value will only be checked for,
  at most, one value.

Is this what you are after?

```js
var dna = document.getElementById("input1");
var rna = [];
var aminoacid;


function replace(){
  let val = dna.value;
  if (val.indexOf('a') > -1) {
    rna.push("u");
  }
  if(val.indexOf('t') > -1){
    rna.push("a");
  }
  if(val.indexOf('c') > -1){
    rna.push("g");
  }
  if(val.indexOf('g') > -1){
    rna.push("c");
  }
  document.getElementById("total").textContent = rna.join("");
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Type DNA's value..." id="input1">
<button type="button" onclick="replace();" id = "button1">Get RNA</button>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Comment: The OP isn't showing all of their code, only the minimum necessary.

Comment: @Dr-Vortex Yes, that is the case with almost all questions here. What's your point? None of my code or comments has anything to do with other code that may or may not be part of the overall project.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Your code works, but isn't what I asked for. I want it to transfer in a sequential order, so in other words check by the input the user puts in, not by the method the code checks it through. For an example, if you type AGT it should in theory transfer to UCA, but the code doesn't translate it to that. Instead, it converts it to UAC, the exact opposite I want it to. Could you update the code to check for that? Thanks!